# comparing the old values vs new value and update

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**NOTE: i havent implement the above solution but closing this question and accepting this as answer even thou i havent implement.**

what is the best way of doing? and i know that i can store the repeater in a different var and compare but i just wanted to know the elegant way of doing.

here is my `for loop` code that i want to compare and update the values that have changed and ignore the values that have not changed

```
GridViewRow row = gv.SelectedRow;            
Repeater _rpt = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("rptReg") as Repeater; 
Repeater _rpt1 = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].FindControl("rptVisitor") as Repeater; 

    for (int i = 0; i < _rpt.Items.Count; i++)   {       
         TextBox _txt = _rpt.Items[i].FindControl("txtId") as TextBox;       
         TextBox _txt1 = _rpt.Items[i].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;     

        if (_rpt1.Items.Count > i)         
           TextBox _txt3 = _rpt1.Items[i].FindControl("txtVisitor") as TextBox;      
          //update db 
        }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a total hack and I'm sure there is a more elegant way to handle it but you could throw a hidden field in there and set up your form elements with an onchange script to update the value of the hidden field. Then just check for the value of the hidden field.

Hopefully someone has a better way to do it than that but if all else fails.

If you add a class to the hidden field of "hiddenIndicator" and to your form elements of "causesChanged" then the following Jquery should do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.causesChanged').change(function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('tr') // get the parent row
            .find("input.hiddenIndicator") // find children that match the selector
            .val('1'); //the value that indicates a change occured
    });
})
```

I haven't tested that code but I used something similar in a project once.

Comment: not sure will that work in my situation and i am using repeater in the edititemtemplate `<EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptName" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </EditItemTemplate>`

Comment: Ah in that case just add a span or a div as the outermost element in the repeater and class that then put the hidden inside the div along with the text box. Change the ".closest" to ".closest('div')" or "span" if you go with the span instead.

Comment: note: i havent implement the above solution but closing this question and accepting this as answer even thou i havent implement.